# Is there any design pattern supports to call required methods automatically?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I am new to design. I want to create class. If any one creates an instance, Object should call methods automatically.

Is there any way like Listeners? If yes, please suggest me.

Comment: Why not add these method calls to the Object's constructor?

Comment: What do you mean automatically?

Comment: Can't you put what you want to do in that class's constructor? Please explain more clearly what you are trying to achieve, possibly with pseudo-code.

Answer (score 2):

I think that you want an Observer Pattern... maybe you can use the mix of Factory an Observer Patterns... see that links...

See http://www.javaworld.com/javaqa/2001-05/04-qa-0525-observer.html

Also http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html

Answer (score 0):

Can you just put the methods you want to call in the class constructor? If not, you could make  a Factory-type class that creates your objects, and also calls the additional methods you need.

Answer (score 0):

Anything required processing should happen as part of the constructor of the object.

If the logic for creating an instance of the class is complicated, consider using the factory pattern - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern

Answer (score 0):

This the perfect scenario for a Factory pattern as the object creation is a bit complex. This can be achieved either by calling the other methods in the constructor or using a factory as I mentioned.

```
public class ObjectFactory{

  public MyObject createObject(){
     MyObject object = new MyObject();
     object.method1();
     object.method2();
     //...
  }
}
```